# DataTables - Is there a way to run initComplete twice?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have an application with many dataTables, 70+, so I am making use of the defaults extension to set all the common configuration settings. But I have not been able to figure out a way to run functions in the initComplete when an individual dataTable has its own initComplete function.

Here is my test code:

```
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "sDom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
    "pageLength": 20,
    "stateSave": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sInfo": ""
    },
    initComplete: function () {
        defaultStuff();
    }
});

var sampleTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "pageLength": 10,       
    "paging": true,
    initComplete: function () {
        customStuff();
    } 
});

function defaultStuff() {
    console.log('Default..');
}

function customStuff() {
    console.log('Custom..');
}
```

When this is run only the custom function is run while I want both the default and custom function to run.

Answer (score 1):

The individual data table's settings override the defaults, which is why `defaultStuff()` never gets called on `#example`.

To achieve this you'd need to make the call manually within the `initComplete` for that table:

```
var sampleTable = $('#example').DataTable({
  pageLength: 10,       
  paging: true,
  initComplete: function () {
    defaultStuff(); // add this here too
    customStuff();
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you listen for [`init.dt`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/init) on tables which needs extra preparation/code upon initialization :

```
$('#example').on('init.dt', function(e, settings, json) {
  //api can be retrieved by
  var api = $('#example').DataTable();
  ...
})
```